# Not being able to use Json data from php page in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse json data which is sent from a php page using jquery but what I get in result is : `{`

I don't know how to fix it,
I'm creating json data in php like below code :

```
$load_op_cm = $DBM -> RunQuery("SELECT * FROM at_ops_cmnts WHERE op_id='$op_id'",true,false);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($load_op_cm);
    $j_result = json_encode($row);
    echo $j_result;
```

And I'm trying to parse this data using jquery which I'm using Jquery `post`  method to send data and get response , And I'm trying to get this part of data which is useful for me : `cm_1_1 : 1`
not just this one but all of `cm_` variables with their values.

when I show the response in html format it's like : 
[image]

this is my jquery code :

```
 $(function(){
            var vop_id = localStorage.getItem('op_id');
            $.post("Requests/OPS.php", //Required URL of the page on server
                {   // Data Sending With Request To Server
                    Load_OP_CM : true,
                    op_id : vop_id
                },
                function(response){  // Required Callback Function
                    var result = response;
                    $.each(result, function (i,elem) {
                        $("#Response").text(elem);
                    });

                });
```

Any suggestion how to get that data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you would need to parse your JSON string `var result = JSON.parse(response);`.
Then when you iterate through you would need to filter the results to only include the keys that contain 'cm_'

```
var filter = "cm_";
$.each(result, function (i,elem) {
    if(i.indexOf(filter) !== -1) {
        console.log(i, elem);
        // Or whatever you need to do…
    }
});
```